# CAShapeLayer fillColor not rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cashapelayer

I have a method that accepts a UIBezierPath as a parameter and draws a shape accordingly.  If I fill the shape with a solid colour it renders fine but if I try to make it a colour with alpha, I first get an ARC warning asking to change the code and use a bridge and then the fill colour does not render at all.

This works, but is not what I want:

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

This generates an ARC warning "implicit conversion of Objective C pointer type UIColor to C pointer CGColorRef".

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f];
```

This runs but no fillColor is applied to the shape:

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f]);
```

Here is the whole code for the method:

```
-(void)drawShape:(UIBezierPath *)standShape {

    [standShapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    selectedStand = standShape;
    standShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    standShapeLayer.path = standShape.CGPath;
    standShapeLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f]);
    NSLog(@"color = %@", standShapeLayer.fillColor); // This logs the correct colour which is not rendered.
    // standShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]; << This works but is not what I need.
    standShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    standShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
    [_imageView.layer addSublayer:standShapeLayer];

}
```

What do I need to do to allow colours with alpha to fill CAShapeLayer shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although what I had written I thought was correct, it clearly wasn't.

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f];
```

Should be:

```
[standShapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f] CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `alpha` is incorrect.

> alpha - The opacity value of the color object, specified as a value
>   from 0.0 to 1.0.

Try to change

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:2.0f]);
```

to

```
standShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.66 blue:0.86 alpha:0.7f] CGColor];
```

Comment: Although you are probably right, the colour still rendered for me with the alpha level being above 1.0.  The problem for me was solved with the addition of 'CGColor' to fillColor property.